# How to unwrap an img properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm aware of `unwrap()`, however, i can't seem to get it to work.

I double click an `img`. It's wrapped with a div, and a div is inserted above the `img` within this wrap. This is for the purpose of an animation. The prepended `div` moves.

I need this all to undo after the animation is done. Currently, i have a clause where if the `img` is double-clicked again, the animated `div` is removed, but the wrapper still remains.

Here is my code:

```
$("#L .A, .B").live('dblclick', function(event) {
  if (event.type === 'dblclick') {
    if ($(this).hasClass('R')) {
      $('#Box').find('.M').remove();
    } else {
      $(this).wrap('<div class="MContain" />');
      $(this).parent().prepend('<div class="M" />');
      $(".M").stop().animate({
        marginTop: '-5px'
      }, 400).animate({
        opacity: '0'
      }, 400);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('R');
    $('.MContain').children().unwrap();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".M").stop().animate({
    marginTop: '-5px'
}, 400).animate({
    opacity: '0'
}, 400).queue(function() {
    //This will be ran after the animation is done, add your code here.
});
```

Comment: @Peeter ; queue is useful for removing the animated div, but i'm still having difficulty unwrapping the img. I tried unwrap from the .M since its parent is the same as the img, but no luck either.

Comment: Could you reproduce it at jsfiddle.net, that way I'll get an idea of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Peeter i didn't quite manage to fix it completely, but i added an if clause that checks to see if the img is already wrapped or not. And if it isn't, then wrap it. I'm satisfied with that, as that is useful for me elsewhere. Thanks for all your help though!